# c# cookies not being written to

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, setcookie

On my content page I have the code (in page_load):

```
    if (Master.pageAction == "remove")
    {
        int removeProductID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        int removeOptionID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["optID"]);
        Master.myBasket.removeFromBasket(removeProductID, removeOptionID);
        //Response.Redirect("viewBasket.aspx");
    }
```

The function remove from basket is defined as:

```
// Removes item from a basket
public void removeFromBasket(int itemsID, int optionsID)
{
    Page myPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

    this.setCookieString("");
    myPage.Response.Write("done");
}
```

And it calls:

```
// Sets cookie date
public void setCookieString(string cookiesData)
{
    Page myPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    HttpCookie basketCookie = new HttpCookie("basket");
    basketCookie["items"] = cookiesData;
    basketCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7d);
    myPage.Response.Cookies.Add(basketCookie);
}
```

I use the setcookiestring function on other pages and it works fine, but this function (removing from the basket) isn't setting the cookie!  It is writing "done" to the top of the page, so the functions are executing.

No warnings, no errors, it's just not updating the cookie.

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you adding a cookie with a value of "" to the HTTP Response?

Comment: It's just for testing, I would put real data in it but I'm just seeing if it's setting it to anything at all.  The value of the cookie isn't changing no matter what I pass in.

Comment: also, easier to access the response as `Response` property of master page (just like in a `Page`), if outside the (master) page just use `HttpContext.Current.Response`.

Comment: Yeah i was going to say that too - i thought you only use HttpContext.Current.Handler when dealing with HttpHandler's - but then i see the cast to Page so was a little confused.

Comment: Why not remove the cookie by setting its expiration? Another question is why not use Value property - are you creating multi-valued cookie. Last thing, can you check from Fiddler or Firebug to see what cookie data is being sent to browser.

Comment: Hmm i've changed my code to using value, it's setting the right value, but it's got 2 cookies now, 1 in path / and the other in path /sitename

Comment: The one with cookiepath / holds the correct values

Comment: Ahhh, the cookie is initially being set with Javascript, that has the /sitename path specified, and .net uses default / path, so I need to get the javascript set cookie method to not specify the path

Comment: Yup fixed now, wasn't specifiying the path in the javascript set cookie method which defaults to current folder, whereas ASP.net defaults cookie path to "/".   Thanks for all comments it helped me solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the cookie initially being set by Javascript with no `path=` attribute being set.  Javascript defaults the cookie path to the current folder, whilst ASP.net defaults to `/`.

Setting the `path=/` in the Javascript set cookie method resolved this issue.